# How do I seperate my desired data from the HTML tags it is enclosed in when web scraping a table with Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("http://armedforceslegalaction.org.uk/for-service-personnel/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    tds = tr.find_all('td', class_="column-5")
    print (tds)
```

I am looking to scrape the Company Name and Email. So far, my code only outputs the email along with the tags and class it is enclosed in.

How can I produce an output that shows BOTH Company name and Email without the tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
nameList = list()
emailList = list()

for i in range(rangeLen):
    nameList.append(soup.find_all('td', class_="column-1")[i].get_text())
    emailList.append(soup.find_all('td', class_="column-5")[i].get_text())

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Company'] = nameList
df['Email'] = emailList

df.to_csv('file.csv', index = False)
```

Sample Output:

```
Kenneth Paterson Solicitors
kpsols-lac@btconnect.com
Montgomery Smith Solicitors
info@montgomerysmith.co.uk
Dallas McMillan Solicitors
Kim@dallasmcmillan.co.uk
```

Comment: Great thank you. I've tried googling about on how I i'd proceed from there to put the data into a CSV file. I don't suppose you can help there too?

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: Where does rangeLen come from trollster?

Comment: rangeLen = len(soup.find_all('td', class_="column-1"))